# SP 2010 REST $filter column

Tags: filter, date-time, rest

I'm trying to filter a list using the REST service. The column im trying to filter is the default column "Modified". My problem is: I can get all itens created today, but not only the items created after noon. It seems like Sharepoint is ignoring the time factor of a datetime column and only comparing the date.

I tried to use the Hour() function but I get a 400 (bad request) error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems to be impossible, so i worked around and used the client object model... shame...

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 REST Interface expects the following format for the `Date` column:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName?$filter=Modified gt datetime'YYYY-MM-DDT12:00:00Z'
```

**JavaScript example**

```
var listTitle = "Requests";
var minDate = getMinDate();
var endpointUrl = "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listTitle + "?$filter=Modified gt datetime'" + minDate.toISOString() + "'";
$.getJSON(endpointUrl, function(data) {
    $(data.d.results).each(function(i,item){
         console.log(item);
    });
});


function getMinDate()
{
    var d = new Date(); 
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
    d.setHours(12);
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    d.setMilliseconds(0);
    return d;
}
```